# Немогу понять почему не работает if not in

Tags: python

Имеется два списока.

```
a = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'nn!', 'rr#', 'tt' ]
b = ['!' , '#']
result1 = []
result2 = []
```

Пишу условия.

```
for i in a:
    for g in b:
        if g in i:
            result1.append(i)
        if g not in i:
            result2.append(i)
```

Первое условие выполняется верно, находит элементы в котором есть символы.

```
result1 = ['nn!', 'rr#']
```

А вот со вторым проблемка. Почему добавляет элементы с символами?

```
result2 = ['aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'bb', 'cc', 'cc', 'nn!', 'rr#', 'tt', 'tt']
```

Comment: Потому что вы написали условие так, что добавляться будут элементы, в которых **хотя бы один** символ из перечисленных отсутствует. В элементе `nn!` отсутствует `#`, поэтому он добавился. В элементе `rr#` отсутствует `!`, поэтому он добавился. А попробуйте написать `n!r#` - он не добавится, потому что все символы присутствуют.

Answer (score 3):

можно записать это все чуть короче, пользуясь возможностями языка

```
a = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'nn!', 'rr#', 'tt' ]
b = ['!' , '#']
result1 = []
result2 = []

for i in a:
   if any(g in i for g in b):
      result1.append(i)
   else:
      result2.append(i)
print(result1, result2)
```

или даже немного с извращением :)

```
for i in a:
   (result1 if any(g in i for g in b) else result2).append(i)
print(result1, result2)
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде `not in` работает как положено, а вот логика кода не совсем верная. Следующий код вернет вам желаемый результат:

```
a = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'nn!', 'rr#', 'tt' ]
b = ['!' , '#']
result1 = []
result2 = []

for i in a:
    contains = False
    for g in b:
        if g in i:
            contains = True
            break

    if contains:
        result1.append(i)
    else:
        result2.append(i)

print(result1)
print(result2)
```